# Ncurses wgetnstr russian?

Tags: c++, linux, locale, ncurses, setlocale

I have troubles with ncurses, especially, I can't find a way to make it work with russian input. Stuff I already tried:

- Linking with ncursesw
- Setting locales (either setlocale(0, "") or setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"))

Neither of this worked, the only thing I get is this:

[image: this]

Neither does it help with just pure mvwprintw

[image: :( here ):]

Code itself:

```cpp
    mvwprintw(stdscr, 4, base, "Enter description: ");
    char *input2 = (char *)malloc(100000);
    wgetnstr(stdscr, input2, 100000);
    string n_description = input2;
```

UPD:
Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "ncurses.h"
#include <clocale>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    initscr();
    start_color();
    use_default_colors();
    curs_set(0);
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    if(setlocale(LC_ALL,"uk_UA.utf8") == nullptr){
        endwin();
        cout << "Error setting locale\n";
        return -100;
    }
    char *input = (char *)malloc(1000);
    wgetnstr(stdscr, input, 1000000000);
    endwin();
}
```

UPD2:
Checking setlocale, return's not NULL, tho still not working

Comment: Please, provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The pictures do not match the code shown.  Also, are you checking the return value of setlocale?

Comment: That's pictured  for input word, but it's absolutely the same as code for description.
Also added example 
Nope, not checking, should I?

Comment: You should only check the return values of calls if you care whether they work.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization) says

> The  library uses the locale which the calling program has initialized.

More to the point, you have to call `setlocale` ***before**** `initscr`.  Like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "ncurses.h"
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    if(setlocale(LC_ALL,"uk_UA.utf8") == nullptr){
        cout << "Error setting locale\n";
        return -100;
    }
    initscr();
    start_color();
    use_default_colors();
    curs_set(0);
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    char *input = (char *)malloc(1000);
    wgetnstr(stdscr, input, 1000000000);
    endwin();
}
```